# Why does St. Thomas Aquinas cite Proverbs 11:14 as Ecclesiastes 4:9?

Tags: biblical-basis, bible-translation, thomas-aquinas

I’m currently doing a read through of “On Kingship” (De Regno) by St. Thomas Aquinas. In paragraph 8, he cites Ecclesiastes 4:9 as saying

> With this in mind, Solomon says [Eccl. 4:9]: “Where there is no governor, the people shall fall.”

I went to lookup this verse in my Bible but it wasn’t there. On closer inspection, the best candidate I could find is Proverbs 11:14, which states:

> Where there is no guidance, a people falls, but in an abundance of counselors there is safety. (ESV)

Oddly, the only translation I can find that says “governors” is the Douay-Rheims translation.

So given this, why does St. Thomas cite Ecclesiastes 4:9 when he’s obviously referring to Proverbs 11:14, and does the latin vulgate play a part in this as that’s where the D-R draws from?

Comment: To be precise, Aquinas only cites Solomon not a particular book or verse. The Latin text doesn't refer to a book by name. That must have been supplied by the translator or editor of your copy

Answer (score 2):

In the 1982 edition of St. Thomas Aquinas's [On Kingship](https://archive.org/details/onkingshiptoking0000thom_s0v3/page/n3/mode/2up) translated by Gerald B. Phelan revised by I. Th. Eschmann, O.P. (as part of the *Mediaeval Sources in Translation* series) your sentence from paragraph 8 ends with a footnote to Prov 11:14 (see [page 6](https://archive.org/details/onkingshiptoking0000thom_s0v3/page/6/mode/2up)):

> In like manner, the body of a man or any other animal would disintegrate unless there were a general ruling force within the body which watches over the common good of all members.  -- With this in mind, Solomon says: "Where there is no governor, the people shall fall." [footnote 7: *Prov. xi, 14*]

In the ESV translation, Proverbs 11 falls under the section Proverbs 10-24 titled "The Proverbs of Solomon" [see pericope title for Prov. 10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%2010&version=ESV).  This section is followed by another section "More Proverbs of Solomon" (Prov. 25-29).  **Therefore, Aquinas's attribution to Solomon is correct.**

As for "governor" and the Latin Vulgate, you are correct that there seems to be a strong link (see Prov. 11 side by side Vulgate and D-R [here](http://catholicbible.online/side_by_side/OT/Prov/ch_11)):

Latin Vulgate:

> Ubi non est gubernator, populus corruet; salus autem, ubi multa consilia.

D-R:

> Where there is no governor, the people shall fall: but there is safety where there is much counsel.

Naturally, the translator for "On Kingship" would use D-R since Aquinas must have used the Vulgate.

Comment: So it must just be my specific book that cites Ecclesiastes 4:9. interesting.

Comment: @LukeHill It appears to be.  I trust the edition cited in my answer because it seems to be a scholarly edition.  The footnote may not be in the original Latin written by Aquinas.

Comment: @LukeHill You inspired me to ask [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/96598/10672).