# Which Bible translations did Aquinas use when writing his commentaries and citing them in his theological works?

Tags: exegesis, bible-translation, thomas-aquinas, bible-commentary

We know that early in his career (as *baccalaureus biblicus*, before he wrote his *Summa*) Aquinas lectured on the Bible and wrote his own commentaries in addition to using the *Catena aurea* as well as Patristic commentaries available to him.

**My question**: When Aquinas did his exegesis, did he have access to the Hebrew/Greek source (although he couldn't read Greek)?  Apart from the Latin Vulgate, did he have access to other translations?

Comment: It's unlikely that he would have used a Hebrew or Greek source, since the Latin Vulgate was the normative text for the Western Church. Surely, he could have accessed the Greek or Hebrew texts, since the East preserved him, and he had access to writings from the East, as he references Jews and Muslims who were near contemporary with him living in the East, such as Maimonides (who died only 20 years before St. Thomas was born).